# resume foreachloop after incrementing php bootstrapp drop down menu

Tags: php, foreach, bootstrap-4, break, resume

**Question in short: i want to output array: 0, 1 , 2 then break, echo something , output 3,4,5 and keep this in a loop.**

Hello everyone i am working on a dynamic php website with bootstrap 4 and php to practice the language. Unfortunately i am now stuck since i dont know how to create something that kindoff looks like an algorith. Allright enough talking and lets get down to the code:

**nav.php file**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class='nav-item dropdown'>
  <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' datatarget='dropdown_target' href='#'>
    <span class='caret'></span>Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_target">
      <!-- <a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown</a> -->
      <?php
      $i=0;
      foreach ($dropItems as $item ) {

        echo "<a class='dropdown-item' href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title] </a>";
        $i++;
        if($i==1) break;
        echo "<a class='dropdown-item'>Dropdown</a>";

      }
       ?>
    </div>
    </li>
</li>


  <?php
    foreach ($navItems as $item ) {
      echo "<li class='nav-item'> <a class='nav-link' href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a> </li>";
    }


   ?>

</ul>
```

**arrays.php**

```
<?php
  //Navigatie menu items
  $navItems = array(

                array(
                  "slug" => "index.php",
                  "title" => "home"
                ),
                array(
                  "slug" => "contact.php",
                  "title" => "Contact"
                ),
                array(
                  "slug" => "market.php",
                  "title" => "Marketplace"
                ),
              );

              $dropItems = array(

                            array(
                              "slug" => "#",
                              "title" => "Lps"
                            ),
                            array(
                              "slug" => "#",
                              "title" => "Sps"
                            ),
                            array(
                              "slug" => "market.php",
                              "title" => "Marketplace"
                            ),
                          );
 ?>
```

Comment: And where do you want to output `0,1,2....`?

Comment: i want to output list item 0,1,2 then divide, then continue with 2,3,4 after the divide and so on as i am continuing to developer the list items further

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_chunk to split the array in the chunks of three and foreach nested with `echo "something";`.

Can't see in your code where this echo of three is so I just made an example of how to do it.

```
$arr = range(1,12); //example array

$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3);

Foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    Foreach($chunk as $val){
        Echo $val ." ";
    }
    Echo "\nsomething\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/0VlN0

Comment: Thank you so much i have solved the issue thanks to your answer :) was a little bit of puzzeling but i got it working here is my code :)

$chunks = array_chunk($dropItems, 2);

      Foreach($chunks as $chunk){
          Foreach($chunk as $item){
              echo "<a class='dropdown-item' href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title] </a>";
          }
          Echo "<div class='dropdown-divider'></div>";
        }

Comment: @T.DT Feel free to accept my answer. This means the answer is solved and can be found as a solved question/problem. click on the tick mark left of my asnwer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andreas i got it working using his method

$chunks = array_chunk($dropItems, 2);

```
      Foreach($chunks as $chunk){
          Foreach($chunk as $item){
              echo "<a class='dropdown-item' href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title] </a>";
          }
          Echo "<div class='dropdown-divider'></div>";
        }
```